# VBA find variable match in table to prevent duplicates

Tags: ms-access, variables, vba, import-from-excel

I have been searching for an answer for how to do this for over a month now with little help.

What I am trying to do:
I have an Access 2013 database (accdb) that I need to import Excel (CSV) reports into.  I got the import VBA working correctly.  I get the reports weekly from a site and would like to use the data better with access.  I am trying to make sure that the import doesn't allow the same report to be imported, to prevent duplicates.  I will be trying to query results from several reports and the imports all go into one table.  I have added a field to the table for import date/time with default `Now()` so I can see which report the record belongs to.  I need to try and update a table with the CSV report filename which is a date (20140625.csv).  I think I got that part working correctly too, the record value is 20140625.

The problem I'm having:
I can't get anything to search for the filename record in the table and then not allow the import if the record matches the filename.  I have tried dlookup and several different things.  Nothing is working.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub ImportCSV()
'First add reference to Microsoft Office Object Library
Dim strfilename As String
Dim rptN As String
Dim rptF As String
Dim look As String


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Title = "Select the CSV file to import"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv", 1
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 2
    If .Show = -1 Then
        strfilename = .SelectedItems(1)
        rptF = Right(strfilename, Len(strfilename) - InStrRev(strfilename, "\"))
        rptN = Left(rptF, InStrRev(rptF, ".") - 1)
        End If
  End With

'dlookup not finding anything but first record in table
 look = DLookup("[rptName]", "tblCSVlog", "[rptName] = 'rptN'")

 If rptN = look Then
 'If rptN = DoCmd.FindRecord("'rptN'") = True Then
    MsgBox "Report " & rptF & " Already Exists"
     GoTo Hell
 'End If
 Else

'Import Works
       DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "GlobalRptCSV", strfilename, True 

'Add FileName to Table Works
       DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert INTO tblCSVlog ([rptName])Values (" & rptN & ")") 
Hell:
'Else
        'Exit Sub
    End If
'End With

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Any ideas?  I tried all kinds of variations of dlookup with variable rptN, "rptN", "'rptN'".  Nothing is finding a match in the table.

Comment: You seem to have confused the variable with its name. Try: `look = DLookup("[rptName]", "tblCSVlog", "[rptName] = '" & rptN & "'")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have confused the variable with its name. Try:

```
look = DLookup("[rptName]", "tblCSVlog", "[rptName] = '" & rptN & "'")
```

Comment: at first it would not work because it hung up on null results.  so i added NZ() and it seems to be working great.  thank you so much.  final vba line was:     `look = Nz(DLookup("[rptName]", "tblCSVlog", "[rptName] = '" & rptN & "'"), "")`

Comment: @user2997752 Sorry, I didn't go too much in the details of the code. But I'm glad that I helped finding the proper solution. :-)